# Module 'SocketIO' was not compiled with library evolution support; using it means binary compatibility for framework can't be guaranteed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, socket.io, xcframework

When I install SocketIO in my Framework project using Swift Package Manager the build is successful but there is a warning "Module 'SocketIO' was not compiled with library evolution support; using it means binary compatibility for 'framework name' can't be guaranteed".

Note: I enabled **Build Libraries for Distribution to YES** in both project target. Socket IO framework I installed in my framework project using Swift Package Manager.(Using cocoa pods xcframework generation is not working for SocketIO).

Eventually I have to generate XCFramework out of this framework project, even If I generate XCFramework with the warning the final .xcframework is not support when I import it any project. Xcode says "Fail to load module SocketIO"

Can any one help me on this? I tried many possibilities from last one week.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the link to library repository that you are trying to integrate?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I think, that we have to wait for Xcode 11.4 and Swift 5.2 release. Then, we can try to create Package.swift for our xcframework and list all dependencies there e.g. SocketIO.

The client app will fetch this manifest and resolve all dependencies.